# Does there exist a sequence $(s_n)$ of partial sums of a series $\Sigma a_n$ where the series diverges and the sequence is bounded and increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Fairly simple question, but I was unable to thing of a good solution.

It is obvious that the sequence can be bounded as it can just be $s_n=(-1)^n$, but I can not figure out how to prove whether or not it can be increasing. My gut instinct is no, but I don't know how I would prove that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any increasing bounded sequence converges, by the monotone convergence theorem. So the sequence $(s_n)_n$ would converge, meaning the series $\sum_n a_n$ would too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence $(s_n)$ of partial sums is increasing and bounded (in particular bounded above) it follows that $s_n$ converges to $\sup_{k} s_k<\infty$. So the series converges.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible indeed if $s_n$ is bounded and increasing it has finite limit, that is converges, and by definition

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n=\sum_{n\ge n_0} a_n$$

Refer to [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).